# How should "bad" language be handled?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

I was just reviewing some edits when I came across an edit where a user with `97` Rep wanted to edit a answer by a user with `12k+`Rep. Just by that I was thinking well this should be good....

So looking at the edit and the description I saw "language is not proper offensive word used". Looking at the code there is an array with some swear words it is and some more words that are offensive.

As a result of this I accepted the edit to change the words used in the array example. Was this the correct decision? Im not sure why this wouldn't have been flagged when the question was asked or if I should flag it now? A user with high rep must be aware of more of the rules of the site, more so then me so it got me thinking.. Is this ok?

Is it ok to use "bad" language on SO? Have I make the correct decision by accepting the edit?

The question / answers I am refering to can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129718/replace-method-is-not-replacing-inputs/21130476#21130476")

***Note***: I am not repeating any of the words in this post, please look at the question and into edits on that page etc.

Comment: Suggested edit in question: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4577505

Comment: The user has 12k, not 20k+. The answer is responding to a post that uses the exact same list of words, as do the other answers. That's because the **question** is about censoring such words. I rolled back the edit in this case.

Comment: I disagree with censorship for censorship's sake - but if you're going to do it, don't leave answers (and their question) inconsistent. Censor all, or censor none.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah yes, not sure why I put `20k`. So you would say it is acceptable in this case?

Comment: @michaelb958 That makes sense, next time I shall do so but overall is this acceptable to be on SO?

Comment: I find it odd; the word they decided to leave

Comment: That user is doing nothing but clean up offensive words in posts; see http://stackoverflow.com/users/3449122/sunil-devre?tab=activity&sort=all

Comment: @Ruddy: I do think the post could have been cleaned up, but *in context*; so clean up the question and other answers as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok that makes sense, thank you for answer. Good to see how other people would handle this situation.

Comment: Actually; given that the word they left was "spelled unusually" and they are only correcting bad language I can't help wondering if they are using a bot. The recent edits seem pretty high frequency

Comment: @RichardTingle, actually that word in various forms isn't widely used in a lot of countries so it wouldn't amaze if they didn't know what it was. Growing up in Australia I really only knew it was 'bad' because of US media / books etc.

Comment: Wonder why the last word has been left unchanged in the edit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, the question is about a problem the user is experiencing while trying to implement a profanity filter system.

That said, I do not see any reason he should post the aforementioned profanity words on SO. The question can basically be reworded as *"how can I replace a word with another"*, so even asking "how to replace 'apples' with 'oranges'" keeps the same result (it is not like he is attempting some sort of heuristic search or such).

IMHO, you did well to accept the edit. Also, if it were for me, I would also have flagged the question as offensive (but I agree that may be a little to much of an overkill. We should consider what the real poster intentions where. Did he not think about it or he didn't care?).

To reassume, I do not see any reason in that question that should allow tolerating offensive word. It is about **replacing an arbitrary string in javascript**, not asking the meaning/usage of a word on a grammar related board.

**Edit:**
Just a little notice about a thing that I didn't notice before. You where asking about editing the answer to the question, not the question in se. I would still have done that, and I would also have edited the question. Offensive words have no place in the topic, question or answers should be considered at the same level. That said, I would have spared the flag to answer since they quoted the actual question (not that I consider it very elegant, but still....).

Comment: In early days on SE I flagged a question as offensive and it was declined by a moderator with a custom reason such as "only flag if the question is purely offensive and can't be fixed with an edit". I now understand and agree with that reasoning.

Comment: @PeterJ why? IMHO that was a lame answer. Fix the thing with an edit, but the user should still receive some sort of correction about is behavior. Do you want someone to just go around posting bad words while the others clean up?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist in the specific context the OP is dealing with, the language may be foul, but the intentions were not. Flagging a moderator does seem overkill when a simple edit will do.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Interesting, thanks for your answer. See im not sure if this should be reported or not. As it wasn't "aimed" at anyone I was leaning more to maybe not. I think the edit should have been made instead. Its good to get other peoples views on it, so thank you!

Comment: @Bart. I agree that flagging may be overkill. But I still believe that it was correct to edit the post (and all the other question/answers)

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not acceptable. You shouldn't have accepted the edit as it changes the original answer. Expletives are not acceptable behavior on SE, but in this case, by removing them you're changing the original meaning of post. Excessive enforcing is bad, and I don't think this edit shoud've been approved.

If you *really* want to remove them, you should remove them from everywhere, not just a single answer. As michaelb958 said in the comments under the question, "*Censor all, or censor none*".

Comment: In this case, the original question has been changed as well. In that light I made similar changes to the answers, so they no longer seem out of place. But granted, that's only due to this specific scenario. All or nothing.

Comment: Very true, but should the OP not have changed the words in the first place? The function would still work the same with other words being used (as people have already edited) so overall should the words have even been used in the first place, I feel it was unnecessary even tho the intention was good.

Comment: @Bart: the question was edited by Andrew Barber; he should've adjusted the answers too when he did that. I guess he responded to a flag and missed the answers.

Comment: Yeah, my guess as well @MartijnPieters. Anyway, I think I fixed all appropriately now.