# Clarification on swearing

Tags: discussion, flags, rude-or-abusive

To me, swearing doesn't fit within the "Be Nice" policy.

Today I asked a post owner to remove the swearing from their post. After that I flagged a post as rude because of this. (I could have edited it myself of course, but I hope letting OP doing it helps them to understand the rules.)

Another user already suggested an edit to remove the swearing (and introduced a fluffly remark along the way). Both the edit and the flag were declined by a moderator (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18149405).

Why was that? Should we allow swearing? Was there another reason the flag was declined? If so, I am happy to learn how to improve my flagging.

Comment: Well a suggested edit *adding* "Thank your for your comments" is one that merits rejection 100% of the time.  In this case I'd reject and edit to also remove the noise in the post, but there's no way that edit should be approved.

Comment: @Servy OP is more asking about his flag for rude than the suggested edit.

Comment: Do you mean the “god damn” part? That’s not swearing where I’m from. Maybe the reviewers were from the same part of the world (or another one that doesn’t consider it swearing)

Comment: Yes, I do. C# can hardly be seen as swearing ;) @Clive

Comment: I think that flag should have been marked helpful, for what it is worth .... Although I personally would not have used a red flag.

Comment: @Walfrat The question asks about both.  If they realize the edit merits rejection, why ask about the edit?

Comment: [How should “bad” language be handled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251102/839601)

Comment: The point was that the mod couldn't have missed the swearing part @Servy

Comment: @Patrick heh, I know someone who’d disagree :) but you sidestepped that one - you consider “god damn” to be swearing, many people don’t - why are you right in this case?

Comment: That is why this is a request for clarification, not a complaint about a mod action @Clive

Comment: It is not rude when the recipient is the poster.  He's just kicking the garbage can, no big deal.

Comment: Not really, if that were the case your question would be _is “god damn” considered swearing?_. Your actual question and comments make it clear you’ve already decided it _is_ swearing, unless I’ve missed something?

Comment: I started my post with "To me". To me that means what follows is subjective.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well a suggested edit *adding* "Thank your for your comments" is one that merits rejection 100% of the time.  In this case I'd reject and edit to also remove the noise in the post, but there's no way that edit should be approved.

As for the abusive flag:  First, this isn't something that requires moderator intervention, or deletion of the post, you can just edit the post to remove the noise, and since you can fix the problem, the flag merits declining.  Second, the post is not being rude or abusive.  It contains some noise, but it's not insulting anyone else or being offensive.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The post was indeed flagged as rude or abusive.

Comment: @BoltClock *After that I flagged a post as rude because of this*. It's written in the question :)

Comment: @Walfrat: Sometimes, people say they flagged a post as rude, when in actuality they custom-flagged it and said "This post is rude." Not remotely the same thing. That's why Servy stated their assumption about what flag was used, and why I'm confirming it.

Comment: @BoltClock No, actually, I just didn't notice that in the question, although I do appreciate you confirming it.